# Why does not global variable need initialization?

Tags: php

I am surprised to see that the global variable does not need any initialization before it can be used in the program. Here's my small snippet which forced me to ask this question:

```
<?php
function set_variable()
{
    global $name;
    //$name = "admin";
}

set_variable();
?>

<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
```

When this code is executed, it all works well. But if I don't make my variable `name` as global then I see `Undefined variable: name` in the textbox. Why does global make a huge difference?

Comment: `global $name;` behaves like `$name = & $GLOBALS["name"];` and thus implicitly creates it (with `NULL` as initial value).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: @mario yes you exactly talked about the point what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is declared outside the function its already in global scope. So there is no need to declare the variable as global.But if you are calling from inside the function you have to use global keyword.Those variable are not accessible inside function unless you declare them with global.

Comment: Here's nothing to talk about variable scope. Read my question carefully again.